# Rename defaultdict key in Python

Tags: python, defaultdict, google-speech-api

I have the following problem: I have a defaultdict called word_count containing words and the number how often they occur. I get this by counting the reply of the Google Speech API. However, this API gives me back things like '\303\266' for the German letter 'ö'.
Now I want to go through this dict, test if one of these things shown above is there and replace it with the right thing like this:

Filling the defaultdict:

```
word_count = defaultdict(int)
for line in fileinput.input([file]):
    line = line.strip()
    words = line.split()
    for word in words:
        word_count[word] += 1
```

So far it works fine, I can print the dict and it gets me the words with the number.

Now replacing the key:

```
for key,val in word_count:
    if '\\303\\266' in key:
        new = key.replace('\\303\\266', 'ö')
        word_count[new] = word_count.pop(key)
```

Now this does not work, I guess because I cannot pop(key) as it expects an integer. How else would I do this? I tried several approaches, but nothing seems to work here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Solution:**

Turns out this was my fault, as I sorted the dict and thereby turned it to a list of tuples. Thanks to everyone who helped me figure this out!

Comment: Any advance on *"does not work"*?

Comment: `word_count.items()`?

Comment: How did `for key,val in word_count:` work? What's the error you are getting?

Comment: I get the error `word_count[new] = word_count.pop(key)
TypeError: an integer is required`

               `for key,val in word_count:` works fine, I can iterate through the dict and print the keys and values

Comment: What are *key* and *val* holding? Did you print them?

Comment: @ozgur: when I `print key`, I get for example `ver\303\266ffentlichen`

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary : when i use `word_count.items()`, I get `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'`

Comment: @KyleButler did you by any chance reassign `word_count` to a list somewhere up in your code?

Comment: @ozgur the only thing I did with word_count is this line, but I thought that only changes the order of the dict? `word_count = sorted(word_count.iteritems(), key=lambda (k,v): (v,k))`

Comment: @KyleButler `sorted` returns a list instead of dict.

Comment: After that it's list of tuple.

Comment: @RahulKP It is a list of tuple but `list.pop` expects an integer parameter whereas `dict.pop` expects any value with a hashable type. (ex: string)

Comment: @ozgur ok well that explains it. So I will read about lists and try renaming it then. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: @KyleButler you can also convert it back to dict again like: `word_count = dict(sorted(word_count.iteritems(), key=lambda (k,v): (v,k)))` if you are sure new keys are unique.

Comment: @ozgur yeah the new keys should be unique. Getting a different error now: `for key,val in word_count:
ValueError: too many values to unpack`I will check this one out, then I can see if your solution works

Comment: `for key,val in word_count.items()`

Comment: Well that is interesting. I used this code now: `new = key.replace('\\303\\266', 'ö')
            word_count[new] = word_count[key]`

And what I got is this: `ver\xc3\xb6ffentlichen`. So it might actually not be the Google API giving me these weird numbers, but maybe this happens somewhere else on the way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the discussions get to know that you are treating with list of tuple instead of `dict`. So `list.pop` always expect a integer that's why you getting an error.

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

And `dict` expect it's key. So here you have to convert the input like `dict` or pop up from list with using it's index.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like so:

```
word_count['ö'] = word_count[key]
```

and then:

```
del word_count[key]
```

Comment: I get `word_count['ö'] = word_count[key]
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str`
And wouldnt I replace the whole key with 'ö' by this? I just want these wrong numbers replaced, not the whole key.